# How to telnet from another server to other server and send command with SSH.net in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, telnet, ssh.net

I am trying to telnet from one server to anther server, I've successfully logged in first server but when I am trying telnet by sending telnet command its not responding.

```
   using (var client = new SshClient("00.000.0.00", 22, "user", "pass"))
        {
            try
            {
                client.Connect();


               client.RunCommand("telnet 00.0.0.000 3300");

               Thread.Sleep(30000);
               client.RunCommand("LOGIN:user:pass");

               Thread.Sleep(30000);
               var cm = client.RunCommand("MY_COMMAND");

               Label1.Text = cm.Result.ToString();
               client.Disconnect();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Label1.Text = ex.Message;
            }

        }
```

Comment: #Kuthar what error you got?

Comment: No error but after a long time i've not got any response..